# SwiftUI: how to observe a simple @State Int value?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to observe the changes of a simple value:

```
@main
struct TestSwiftUIApp: App {
    @State var test: Int = 0
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(value: $test)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        fetchNewTest()
    }
    
    func fetchNewTest() {
        test = test == 0 ? 1 : 0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.fetchNewTest()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

However, nothing happens in `fetchNewTest()` so I don't really understand what happens with this variable. Could you please help me?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your code to this down way and use onAppear, you cannot and you should not use init of views in SwiftUI.

```
@main
struct TestSwiftUIApp: App {
    @State var test: Int = 0
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(value: $test)
                .onAppear() { fetchNewTest() } // <<: Here!
        }
    }

    func fetchNewTest() {
        test = test == 0 ? 1 : 0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.fetchNewTest()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
            .padding()
    }
}
```